# Continuity of a two-variable function?

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

I have to check if the function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y}{2x^6+y^2}$$
can be defined at $f(0,0)$ so that it is continuous at $(0,0)$.
I first checked for $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y}{2x^6+y^2}$ along $x=0$ and got that the limit equals zero. Then I checked for $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y}{2x^6+y^2}$ along $y=x^3$ and the limit equals $\frac{1}{3}$. Is it safe to conclude that the function cannot be defined at $f(0,0)$ because  $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^3y}{2x^6+y^2}$ does not exist? 
Is my way of solving the problem valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your way of solving the problem is valid. To elaborate on the machinery underneath the approach you are using, if the limit
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow a}f(z)=L
$$
exists, then any sequence $(z_{n})_{n}$ converging to $a$ should converge to the same limit:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(z_{n})=L.
$$

In your example, $z=(x,y)$ and $a=0$. What you have done, implicitly, is found two sequences
$$
z_{n}=(0,y_{n})\text{ and }z_{n}^{\prime}=(x_{n},x_{n}^{3})
$$
(both converging to zero) that converge to different limits. Therefore, by contradiction, the original limit
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow0}f(z)
$$
does not exist.